# Home button unresponsive due to Mail?

Tags: iphone, hardware

I've recently started to notice that my home button has been a little unresponsive. Sometimes a single click won't work at all and it takes a few tries to get it to quit an app. Sometimes two clicks does what one click is supposed to do, sometimes it just doesn't work the way it's supposed to. A firm double tap that is slightly spaced out seems to solve it, but here's the strangest thing that I discovered. I did a hard reset and it helped and everything was normal. Then I did a restore to a backup and it helped a little (I don't want to have to start over again with a fresh fresh install, I'll save it for iOS 5). I was experimenting quitting various apps to see what would happen, since it seems like it could help. Quitting out of intensive applications such as the app store or other apps that take up a lot of memory did nothing. What does fix it immediately is force quitting mail. I've tried it with the other Apple supplied applications and it did nothing. There are only two gmail accounts there so i'm not sure what could be the problem. Anyone else out there have this/heard of this/ have any advice?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.

•Close all aps on the phone.
   (by hitting the red "x"s on the multi tasking tray.)

•Open Safari

•Hold down the power button until you get the "side to power off screen"
   (do not power off)
•While on that screen hold down the home button lightly for 20 seconds.

•If done right you should be sent to the home screen

Congratulations you just re-calibrated your home button.  It should work better.

Comment: That really doesn't make sense. Do you have a source for this procedure?

Comment: thanks for the tip. I had always assumed this was a hardware problem. Tip worked perfectly to resolve "sticky" home button

Comment: it does actually work... but how does it re-calibrate your home button?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It appears the home button settings are stored on a separate piece of RAM that doesn't get refreshed and deteriorates over time. This fixed it right up.

Comment: This is a myth. You're just force-quitting Safari with this method. http://www.marco.org/2012/01/08/drang-home-button-calibration-voodoo https://twitter.com/chpwn/status/156249439017766912

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't just an intermittent hardware issue with the home button ?

I'm on my fourth iPhone 4 now, after the first three all developed problems wit the home button. In each case replacing the hardware fixed the problem, for a couple of months.

Comment: I wished it was an intermittent hardware issue that I could just get replaced but I immediately see results when I quit mail out of the switcher bar